# Combine Bootstrap columns and FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got some mixed concepts right here. What Im trying to achieve is, in a set of bootstrap containers, combine flexbox with bootstrap columns and make the last images ("img-team") resize according to his containers. They are resizing according to width but not to height. When is height what exceed the container just get bigger. What´s happening in the HTML is that one big container set the height property. Then in the subdivs, the space is dividing up according to flex-grow:1 or not flex:0.

DRAW OF PRETENDED
[image] I want the image to adapt that div, not to change the height of the big orange container. Its currently working but not with height increment, just for width increment.

HTML

```css
.img-team {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; flex-flow: column; flex: 0 0 50vh">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; flex-flow: column; flex-grow: 1">
    <div>
      <h4 class="">TITLE</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
        <div style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0">
          <img class="img-team" src="img/team-1.jpg" href=""></img>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
          <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
        <div style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
          <img class="img-team" src="" href=""></img>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
          <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
        <div style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
          <img class="img-team" src="" href=""></img>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
          <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
        <div style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
          <img class="img-team" src="" href=""></img>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
          <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. With no image. Everything fit and goes well.
   [image]
2. With image. Contain doesnt fit anymore (only fit width not height). Thats why I think its cause of the image.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but this might help:

1. Check the styles for div `.img-team-wrap`, it's a wrapper div for images with padding-top, in this case it's 100% to maintain the aspect ratio of the DIV 1:1 you can find more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)
2. than use the styles from `.img-team` for the images to center it inside the div.
3. Also add `flex: 1` and `justify-content: flex-end;`. to each column, I think this solves the issue.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
}

.top-content,
.team-wrap {
  height: 50vh;
}

.team-wrap>div {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.img-team-wrap {
  padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative; /* For Positioning Image Inside */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-team {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 101%;
  width: 101%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; flex-flow: column; flex: 0 0 100%">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; flex-flow: column; flex-grow: 1">
      <div class="top-content">
        <h4 class="">TITLE</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row team-wrap" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
          <div class="img-team-wrap" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1;">
            <img class="img-team" src="https://sparkwebservices.com/img/ww-1.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
            <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
          <div class="img-team-wrap" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
            <img class="img-team" src="https://sparkwebservices.com/img/ww-2.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
            <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
          <div class="img-team-wrap" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
            <img class="img-team" src="https://sparkwebservices.com/img/ww-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
            <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: column">
          <div class="img-team-wrap" style="display:flex; flex-grow: 1">
            <img class="img-team" src="https://sparkwebservices.com/img/ww-1.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 class="xxx">Walter White</h4>
            <h4 class="xxx">More text</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. The parent div has flex, its just that the code is kind of messy and I havent pasted it all. Regarding the object-fit property. I already tried that but still not working. Im gonna edit the question to show some images to clarify.

Comment: @JuanJesus can you please add those images inside the question content?

Comment: Done, also tried your code but exactly the same happens :/

Comment: The strange behaviour is that, if dont put the image, all the containers adapt perfectly one by one as expected, but when I put the image, even if its 100% both, it just doesn´t fit well.

Comment: @JuanJesus can you check now? BTW, each image has different size - so it works with any image size and ratio.
Also, remove `href` attribute from images, because t's not valid.

Comment: Man finally, that works. Im gonna cry. Now I have another problem. This is finishing me off. Problem is that doing this (position absolute and relative) break bootstrap grid sistem and now I always see 4 Walter Whites. If you have an advice or way to solve it thanks. If not, thanks you so much for your help and interest on helping. Really, thanks a lot man.

Comment: No need to say I havent comprehend anything, but the code just do what was pretended so ofc marked solution. thanks!

Comment: @JuanJesus I'm glad this works, can you post a screenshot of the new issue?

Comment: Im not working on this anymore. This is finishing me off haha. Thanks for your help. Regards